# Cannot detach persistent disk in gcloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm pretty sure my problem is that I detached the disk before I unmounted it, that is to say I did the command:

```
gcloud compute instances detach-disk instance-1 --disk disk-1 --zone us-central1-a
```

before doing:

```
$ sudo umount /dev/disk/by-id/google-persistent-disk-1
```

Now that I've done that I have to figure out how to detach the disk so that I won't be charged for it. The old mountpoint for my disk was `/mnt/disks/temp_dir`.  So when I run

```
kylefoley@instance-1:/mnt/disks/temp_dir$ touch hey_man.txt
```

I get the following error:

```
touch: cannot touch 'hey_man.txt': Input/output error
```

When I run

```
kylefoley@instance-1:/dev/disk/by-id$ ls
```

I get

```
google-instance-1         scsi-0Google_PersistentDisk_instance-1
google-instance-1-part1   scsi-0Google_PersistentDisk_instance-1-part1
google-persistent-disk-1  scsi-0Google_PersistentDisk_persistent-disk-1
```

So then I run

```
kylefoley@instance-1:/$ sudo umount /dev/disk/by-id/google-persistent-disk-1
```

And get:

```
umount: /dev/disk/by-id/google-persistent-disk-1: not mounted
```

So then I try to mount the disk with

```
kylefoley@instance-1:/$ sudo mount -o discard,defaults /dev/sdb mnt/disks/temp_dir
```

But that gives:

```
mount: special device /dev/sdb does not exist
```

I also tried attaching the disk from my laptop with

```
Admins-MacBook-Pro-4:other kylefoley$ gcloud compute instances attach-disk instance-1 --disk disk-1 --zone us-central1-a
```

And that basically worked.  The disk also shows up on my console. Don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce your issue up to the point to detaching a disk while in issue (which is a concern).

I was only getting the error Input/output error while the disk was detached and I tried to access known files.

Using [gcloud attach](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/attach-disk) command and mounting the disk normally I was able to access the data without any issues.

```
gcloud compute instances attach-disk instance-1 --disk=disk-1 --zone=ZONE
```

About detaching the disk to not being charged, you will be charged even if the disk is not attached to any instance

From the output of ls /dev/disk/by-id it is clear you have a second disk but it's name is not sdb. One thing I noticed during my reproduction is that the disk change name the second time I attached it (from sdb to sdc).

Try running `sudo blkid` or sudo `fdisk-l` to confirm the disk name

I was able to [detach](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/detach-disk) the disk using gcloud or the webUI

```
gcloud compute instances detach-disk instance-1 --disk=disk-1 --zone=ZONE
```

If the above command does not work please provide the output with the flag --log-http

```
gcloud compute instances detach-disk instance-1 --disk=disk-1 --zone=us-central1-a --log-http
```

Comment: Changing `sdb` to `sdc` seems to have done the trick but I'm not entirely sure. When I input `kylefoley@instance-1:~$ sudo mount -o discard,defaults /dev/sdc mnt/disks/temp_dir` I get:`mount: mount point mnt/disks/temp_dir does not exist` But that seems wrong because when I input: `kylefoley@instance-1:/mnt/disks/temp_dir$ touch what.txt` followed by `kylefoley@instance-1:/mnt/disks/temp_dir$ ls` I get: `what.txt`.  So it seems like I'm getting an error message even though the machine is working.

Comment: Also, strange is that when I try to unmount the disk properly and detach I get the error message that it is not mounted: `sudo umount /dev/disk/by-id/google-persistent-disk-1` gets me `umount: /dev/disk/by-id/google-persistent-disk-1: not mounted`.

Comment: Also I don't think the `sdc` disk is the same as the old `sdb` disk because the old `sdb` disk has a file on it which is not on the `sdc` disk.

Comment: Still I should be able to unmount the `sdc` disk but I cannot.

Comment: I'm still having problems unmounting the disk.  The instructions clearly say to unmount disks before detaching them, otherwise data might get destroyed, so if I cannot unmount disks, then the whole google cloud becomes useless since I will always be afraid that my project will get corrupted.  So when I input: `ls dev/disk/by-id/` I would think that I should be able to unmount those disks but I cannot.  The command: `sudo umount /dev/disk/by-id/google-persistent-disk-1` yields `umount: /dev/disk/by-id/google-persistent-disk-1: not mounted`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to detach the disk, then start over.  So first I hit

```
gcloud compute instances detach-disk instance-1 --disk disk-1 --zone us-central1-a
```

I then looked up the available mounts, using:

```
kylefoley@instance-1:/dev/disk/by-id$ sudo lsblk
```

which gave:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0  10G  0 disk 
└─sda1   8:1    0  10G  0 part /
```

Then I reattached the disk:

```
gcloud compute instances attach-disk instance-1 --disk disk-1 --zone us-central1-a
```

I then looked up the mounts again so that I could get the name of the disk that I mounted:

```
kylefoley@instance-1:/dev/disk/by-id$ sudo lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0   10G  0 disk 
└─sda1   8:1    0   10G  0 part /
sdb      8:16   0  500G  0 disk
```

So the disk is named `sdb`.

I then followed the usual instructions for mounting the disk:

```
sudo mkdir -p /disk1_dir
kylefoley@instance-1:/$ sudo mount -o discard,defaults /dev/sdb /disk1_dir
```

I then checked to see if the file that was in the disk before was still there which was named `huh.txt` and it was:

```
kylefoley@instance-1:/$ cd disk1_dir
kylefoley@instance-1:/disk1_dir$ ls
huh.txt  lost+found
```

Problem solved.